# Electric Field of Perpendicular Charged Sheets

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

If we have two charged infinite sheets of charge density $\sigma$ and $-\sigma$ at right angles, how does the electric field look between them?

By using Gauss's law to get that the field from one sheet is $\vec{E}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\vec{n}$ and superimposing these, I get that the field lines are diagonal lines. But doesn't the field lines always have to be perpendicular to a conductor?

Comment: They only have to be perpendicular at the surface of the conductor. That's it.

Comment: Yeah but I think my calculations don't give perpendicular fields at the surfaces either. Sorry for the confusion. @ubuntu_noob

Answer (score 3):

Implicit in your calculation is that the sheets are non-conducting. If they where conducting, the electric field of one would distort the charge distribution of the other, and the resulting charge distributions would not be uniform.